# Exception: Cannot redeclare function in web.php, but it is the only occurrence of this function

Tags: php, laravel

In my `web.php` File I have a function called `GetRandomString`, and when i type 'php artisan config:cache' to reloud the .env file i get the following error:

> Whoops\Exception\ErrorException  : Cannot redeclare GetRandomString()
>   (previously declared in routes/web.php:171)

But this is exactly the same function. I also haven't declared it anywhere else. The function starts at line 171 and ends at line 179:

```
function GetRandomString($length = 12) {
      $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!';
      $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
      $randomString = '';
      for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
          $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
      }
      return $randomString;
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've have same problem (only when using artisan or phpunit), not found proper solution. I have used:

```
if (!function_exists('GetRandomString')) {
   function GetRandomString($length = 12) {
      ...
   }
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php

Answer (score 4):

Looks like web.php file including twice during one request flow. Use `include_once` or `require_once` to include `web.php` file.

You can also use `function_exists` function to check is function already defined.

```php
if (!function_exists('GetRandomString')) {
    function GetRandomString($length = 12) {
        $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!';
        $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }
        return $randomString;
   }
}
```